# KeyError: 'ibm_db_sa' when trying to use db2 with Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

I've setup a database connection using `sql_alchemy_conn = ibm_db_sa://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}:50000/airflow` in the `airflow.cfg` file.

When I run `airflow initdb`, it pops up `KeyError: 'ibm_db_sa'`. How can I use a DB2 connection with Airflow?

===============

Here is more specific error message:

```
airflow initdb
[2017-02-01 15:55:57,135] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
DB: ibm_db_sa://db2inst1:***@localhost:50000/airflow
[2017-02-01 15:55:58,151] {db.py:222} INFO - Creating tables
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda/bin/airflow", line 15, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 524, in initdb
    db_utils.initdb()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 106, in initdb
    upgradedb()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 230, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 174, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 416, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 93, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 79, in load_module_py
    mod = imp.load_source(module_id, path, fp)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 74, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 65, in run_migrations_online
    compare_type=COMPARE_TYPE,
  File "<string>", line 8, in configure
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 773, in configure
    opts=opts
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 159, in configure
    return MigrationContext(dialect, connection, opts, environment_context)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.impl = ddl.DefaultImpl.get_by_dialect(dialect)(
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 65, in get_by_dialect
    return _impls[dialect.name]
KeyError: 'ibm_db_sa'
```

Comment: I'm running into the same error. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yea, I dont think this is going to work; airflow uses alembic; which does not have support for ibm_db ; airflow passes along your SQLalchemy string, it then takes the first part of your string as a dialect (i.e postgres), it looks up its migration files [it supports mysql,postgres,mssql,oracle,sqllite] so while SQLalchemy works, it doesnt look like alembic does, which is why you get this error. You could write a migration file and put it in alembic or try this https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/offline.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the required package for db2? Eg. `pip install ibm_db_sa`. By the way the pypi page lists that it is only compatible with python 3.

Please note that db2 is not officially supported as a backend for Airflow.